# Роли пользователя в реляционной базе данных

Tags: mysql, база-данных, postgresql, реляционная-модель

В таблице users (далее будет как юзер) есть свойство role которое может принимать одно из значений: ADMIN, DISPATCHER, CLIENT.
Получается что один юзер может имеет одну роль, для каждой роли я хочу иметь возможность хранить дополнительные данные о юзере. Так же для каждой роли я хочу ограничить доступ к некоторым http запросам, насколько я знаю это уже реализуется в REST API через проверку свойства role у авторизованного пользователя.

Исходя из моих требований я сделал прототип БД (названия для profile таблиц взяты с потолка), хочу узнать правильно ли я проставил связи? Может быть есть какой нибудь проверенный временем подход к проектированию того что я пытаюсь сделать?
[image: прототип бд, роли пользователя]

На фронте это примерно будет выглядеть так
Пользователь вбивает логин:пароль выбирает роль, отправляет форму. После нажатия на кнопку, на сервер уходит post запрос у которого в body - login, pass, role. Логин и пароль проходят валидацию если она успешна создается новый user, следующий это шаг проверка какая роль была передана допустим это был ADMIN создается новая строка в AdminProfile связная один к одному к недавно созданному юзеру.

```
<form action="">
  <input type="text" placeholder="login">
  <input type="text" placeholder="password">
  <select name="" id="">
    <option value="ADMIN">ADMIN</option>
    <option value="CLIENT">CLIENT</option>
    <option value="DISPACTHER">DISPACTHER</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Добавить пользователя">
</form>
```

Comment: копайте в сторону фреймворков с ролевым разграничением доступа. Фреймворк уже умеет хранить роли в БД. И в роли не должно быть никаких дополнительных данных о пользователя. Не смешивайте зоны ответственности

Comment: @ArchDemon роль определяется в свойстве role в таблице у user, все же остальные таблицы лишь хранят в себе ряд дополнительных свойств для юзера который имеет ту или иную роль, то есть никакого отношения к роли они и не имеют вовсе. Фреймворки для чего? для проектирования БД? я же вроде сказал что разграничение ролей на уровне REST API мне понятно как сделать, стоит лишь вопрос как хранить дополнительные данные в БД.

Comment: Вы сами себе противоречите "для каждой роли я хочу иметь возможность хранить дополнительные данные о юзере". Храните дополнительные данные в БД в таблице

Comment: *один юзер может имеет одну роль, для каждой роли я хочу иметь возможность хранить дополнительные данные о юзере.* В этих условиях ТРИ дополнительные таблицы (да даже бы и одна) смотрятся ну весьма избыточным решением. Тем более что эти дополнительные данные совсем не похожи на те, что требуют сложной обработки. Одного поля с сериализованными данными (например, в JSON) за глаза имхо.

Comment: @Akina на самом деле в вопросе я очень упростил, будущий проект это должен быть довольно большой и масштабируемой crm, данных будет очень много и некоторые из них многозначительные.